# Price of barriers in black scholes

Tags: black-scholes, price, barrier

Do you know a simple way or proxy, formula to determine the price of a down and out call with strike 100, barrier 100, spot 110 in a BS world with no rate and a 10% vol ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: There are closed-form solutions for (European-style) barrier options in the Black-Scholes model, see [Hull's book](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Hull-Options-Futures-and-Other-Derivatives-10th-Edition/PGM333301.html).

Comment: Espen Haug also has an interesting paper for [American](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=151315)